# Apply wordpress filter checking category

Tags: filters, excerpt

I am trying to apply wordpress filter hook get_the_expert. My intention is to apply filter only when the category slug is "MY-CATEGORY-SLUG". How can I check the category slug inside the filter hook function.

Thanks

Comment: The category slug of the current category being viewed (category archive page)? The category of the current post in the loop?

Comment: Yes category of the current post in the loop.

Comment: Please clarify - by "apply wordpress filter hook", do you mean that you wish to only show the excerpt if a Post is in the category **MY-CATEGORY-SLUG**?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response David. I found the solution. I added the following code in functions.php

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'process_excerpt');

function process_excerpt($param) {
    global $post;
    if(in_category('MY-CATEGORY-SLUG',$post))
        return 'adding some data'.$param;
    else
        return $param;
}
```

This fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, and glad I helped you find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, this code below should help you (place it in **functions.php**).

```
function my_filter_the_excerpt($excerpt){

    global $post;

    /** Return the excerpt only if the post is in the category 'MY-CATEGORY-SLUG' */
    return (in_category('MY-CATEGORY-SLUG', $post) ? $excerpt : ''; 

}
```

Just in case you are unsure of where this code should go, I'd recommend addig the filter just before your Loop starts, and then removing it at the end -

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'my_filter_the_excerpt');
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();

        { your code }

    endwhile;
endif;
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'my_filter_the_excerpt');
```

For more information, I'd recommend having a look at the following documents -

- [The `get_the_excerpt` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt)
- [The `wp_get_post_categories()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories)

Answer (score 0):

As you are inside the loop and you want to **apply the filter** only when the current post is assigned to specific category, you could do something like this in the loop:

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {

        the_post();

        if( in_category( 'MY-CATEGORY-SLUG', get_the_ID() ) ) {
            //The post is assigned to "MY-CATEGORY-SLUG", add the filter
            add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'filter_the_excerpt');
        } else {
            //The post is NOT assigned to "MY-CATEGORY-SLUG", remove the filter
            remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'filter_the_excerpt');
        }

    }
}
```

But I think you should **apply the filter always** and check the category inside the filter, so you can avoid the checking in the loop in order to keep the loop and themplates clean:

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'filter_the_excerpt');
function my_filter_the_excerpt( $excerpt ){

    if( in_category( 'MY-CATEGORY-SLUG', get_the_ID() ) ) {
        //The post is assigned to "MY-CATEGORY-SLUG"
        //Do whatever you want
    } else {
        //The post is NOT assigned to "MY-CATEGORY-SLUG"
        //Do whatever you want
    }


}
```